# Having a Hard Time Incorporating Arrays in Object Oriented Programming In Java

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I was assigned an assignment that creates two classes (UsedCars and TestCars) using object oriented programming.

The assignment has 6 private attributes, 2 constructors (with and without arguments), and 10 accessors and mutators. Then a way to display the results.

The second class will test UsedCars with a Corolla and a Taurus.

The last instruction is what I'm having trouble with:
"Finally create an array of 100 used cars called Cars. Initialize them with a FOR loop to the defaults created in the original constructor and then display Cars[53]."

Here's what I have:

```
public class UsedCars {
private String make = "No Make";
private String model = "No Model";
private int year = 0;
private int miles = 0;
private double price = 0;
private int numberInLot = 0;

UsedCars() {numberInLot++;}

UsedCars(String newMake, String newModel, int newYear, int newMiles, 
        double newPrice) {
    make = newMake;
    model = newModel;
    year = newYear;
    miles = newMiles;
    price = newPrice;
    numberInLot++;
}//used cars

public String getMake() {
    return make;
}//get make

public void setMake(String newMake) {
    make = newMake;
}//set make

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}//get model

public void setModel(String newModel) {
    model = newModel;
}//set model

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}//get year

public void setYear(int newYear) {
    year = newYear;
}//set year

public int getMiles() {
    return miles;
}//get miles

public void setMiles(int newMiles) {
    miles = newMiles;
}//set miles

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}//get price

public void setPrice(double newPrice) {
    price = newPrice;
}//set price

public void display() {
    System.out.println("Make: " + make);
    System.out.println("Model: " + model);
    System.out.println("Year: " + year);
    System.out.println("Miles: " + miles);
    System.out.println("Price: $" + price);
}//display

public int getNumberInLot(int numberInLot) {
    return numberInLot;
}

public void displayNumberOfCars() {
    System.out.println("Number of cars on the lot: " + numberInLot);
}//display number of cars
```

}

And here's the test:

```
public class TestCars {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    UsedCars Car1 = new UsedCars();
    Car1.setMake("Toyota");
    Car1.setModel("Corolla");
    Car1.setYear(1999);
    Car1.setMiles(128000);
    Car1.setPrice(5000.0);
    Car1.display();

    System.out.println();

    UsedCars Car2 = new UsedCars();
    Car2.setMake("Ford");
    Car2.setModel("Taurus");
    Car2.setYear(1992);
    Car2.setMiles(212000);
    Car2.setPrice(2000.0);
    Car2.display();

    System.out.println();

    Car1.displayNumberOfCars();

    System.out.println();
}//main

UsedCars[] Cars = new UsedCars[100];

for (int i = 0; i < Cars.getNumberInLot; i++) {
    System.out.println(Cars[i].)
}

public static int carLot(UsedCars[] Cars) {

}//car lot
```

}

I would appreciate any help you guys can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not initializing the array of objects you are creating.

It says : 
**"Finally create an array of 100 used cars called Cars. Initialize them with a FOR loop to the defaults created in the original constructor and then display Cars[53]."**

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    Cars[i] = UsedCars(); // I dont know which constructor to use here for DEFAULTS
}
```

Then you can print all values by

```
Cars[53].display();
```

And do all of these things inside main function of class **TestCars**

Comment: Also, the `numberInLot` varaible should be static if you want to count the number of `Cars` objects you create.